# VBA in Excel - Copy past values of a range of cells to other cells

Tags: excel, vba, copy-paste

Looking for some help,

I have created a command button and attached the following macro:

```
Private Sub CommandButton1_Click()
Range("J2:J3000").Copy
Range("G2:G3000").PasteSpecial xlPasteValues, xlNone, SkipBlanks
End Sub
```

The task im doing is very simple, copy values only from cells from range J2:J3000 to G2:G3000 but skip blanks when pasting to the corresponding row cell. (J2 copy, paste to G2) This isnt working as its overriding data in the range G2:G3000 with blanks from J2:J3000 instead of pasting the data only

To give context to the ranges.

J2:J3000 has a function

```
=IF(ISNA(VLOOKUP(A2,H:H,1,FALSE)),"","Yes")
```

which is checking data in the sheet that is manually pasted into column H:H and deleted with different data daily.

G2:G3000 has blank text cells where the results from J2:J3000 is then manually pasted to the corresponding row under column G.

(Basically, checking the value returned from the lookup, if it says yes then its manually copied to the cell in column G on the matching row.)

I am trying to introduce a button macro that can paste value returned the lookup and automate this process.

```
Private Sub CommandButton1_Click()
Range("J2:J3000").Copy
Range("G2:G3000").PasteSpecial xlPasteValues, xlNone, SkipBlanks
End Sub
```

Comment: Can you share a screenshot showing starting point and the output? Your example should cover the scenario with blanks and how they should be handled

Comment: @urdearboy here a recording [link](https://vimeo.com/794643732)

Comment: @urdearboy, thats ok. I will try explain further.

So, column H is used to enter data gathered from an external source, its basically an extension number. When this data is pasted into the column H cells Column J does a vlookup based on the extensions in the sheet (Column A:A) the function in column J then inputs a value of Yes if the the extension in column H is matched from Column A - the yes is reflected against the matching row to the extension in column A (hope this makes sense). 

So once the yes is seen in column J I have to manually copy that to Column G on the matching row.

Comment: @urdearboy, So to automate this process i created a macro which should paste the values from Column J. The data manually pasted into Column H is then deleted until the next batch of data is entered where it is pasted. I click the macro button but the macro is overriding the previous data in column G where there are blanks in column J being pasted.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your current method is overwriting everything in `Column G`

To correct this you can work with filtered ranges or utilize loops to conditionally update values in `Column G`. A loop solution is below:

---

```
Sub Test()

'Update the sheet name
Dim ws As Worksheet: Set ws = ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Sheet1")
Dim i As Long

For i = 2 To 3000
    If ws.Range("J" & i).Value = "Yes" Then
        ws.Range("G" & i).Value = ws.Range("J" & i).Value
    End If
Next i

End Sub
```

---

For now this is manually hardcoded to stop at row 3,000. It is likely better to change this to be dynamic. To do this you just need to add a new variable (*`lr` for 'last row'*) to store value of last row and modify the loop to iterate up until `lr` instead of the hardcoded value `3,000`. Relevant bits of code are below

```
Dim i As Long, lr As Long

lr = ws.Range("J" & ws.Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row

For i = 2 To lr
    'If .......
Next i
```

Comment: This now has the results expected, thank you for you help on this. I agree the dynamic would be suited as the list will be growing. Could you share that also?

Comment: @danielbaird, solution has been updated with details needed to make dynamic